# Cobalt app support for Android touch screen devices

Tags: cobalt

As of now , cobalt app works fine with RCU for Android TV's. If we try to test the same app in any touch screen devices, functionality doesn't works properly.
Is there any way to build Android cobalt app for touch screen devices.
Below are the major issues on touch devices.

- Cant scroll
- Not able to pause/resume the video

Comment: Please provide details about "functionality doesn't works properly".  Are there any log warnings or errors that you get when running on a touch screen device that you do not get on the other devices?  The more detail you provide, the better chance someone can help.  Good luck!

Comment: I dont see any extra warnings or error logs in non working cases compared to working case.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your Starboard implementation doesn't emit touch or mouse events. See `kSbInputDeviceTypeTouchScreen` and `kSbInputDeviceTypeMouse` in https://cobalt.dev/reference/starboard/modules/input.html. For example of mouse implementation, see
https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/refs/heads/master/starboard/android/shared/input_events_generator.cc.

Comment: Actually problem is only with the scrolling content . It works fine with USB mouse scroller, but with gesture(touch) movements , it doesn't scroll.

Comment: Interesting, I thought Cobalt doesn't support scrolling at all.